# Getting "%" into javascript output

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

could someone please help a complete javascript noob?  My google-fu seems to be completely lacking...

I'm trying to convert this...

```
var $win = jQuery(window),
w = 0,h = 0,
sgcolour = [],
getWidth = function() {
 w = $win.width();
 h = $win.height();
};
$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {
 sgcolour = [
  Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
  Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
  150,
  1
 ];
 jQuery(document.body).css('background','rgba('+sgcolour.join(',')+')');
}).resize();
```

[Here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fq74/4/)

from rgba to hsla, with x-axis as hue, y as saturation, & other values fixed.

I think I've got the obvious (change 'rgba', set values from thos appropriate to rgba to those appropriate to hsla), but can't for the life of me work out how to get it to output "%" after the required values...

I hoped I'd be able to work it out for myself, but I'm not sure if I even know enough about it to google the right questions :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a string, you can just concatenate `'%'`, so I'm not really sure what the problem is:

```
...
sgcolour = [
   Math.round(e.pageX/w * 360),
   Math.round(e.pageY/h * 100) + '%',
   '50%',
   1
];
jQuery("body").css('background','hsla('+sgcolour.join(',')+')');
```

Note that this is not a *direct* conversion at all.  If you want it to do that then I would suggest using your current `rgb` method and then converting it to `hsl` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.

The problem is that I'm completely clueless about javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

`int/int` results as an `int` (so 0 or 1).

You should multiply before dividing:

```
Math.round(e.pageX * 255 / w),
Math.round(e.pageY * 255 / h),
```

And you wouldn't need to `Round` the value, since it's of type `int`.

```
(e.pageX * 255 / w),
(e.pageY * 255 / h),
```

Comment: *whoosh* (that was the sound of that answer going waaaay over my head)

Not sure if I explained properly even.

the above outputs "background: rgba(xxx,xxx,150,1);" into css, I want...

"background: hsla(xxx,xxx%,50%,1);"

So I just need to know how to insert the "%" symbol in the right place, I think. ???

(the 50 for the third figure is just an example, it's just the insertion of the %)

Comment: He's saying that your code `e.pageX/w` will not give you a float (fractional) result. It will give you 0 or 1. If you change your code to what he suggests, you will get the correct result. Then worry about the % sign (see below answer)